# Enhanced regex for FirstName LastName

Tags: regex

I've reviewed many regex recommendations but unfortunately they were either too restrictive (offending some persons by preventing enter their real name correctly) or too liberal, I mean allowing enter garbage like '---'.

Unfortunately I am not a regex guru, I can understand medium complex regex, and maybe can modify simple changes, but now I am stuck

Here is my starter (with all accented letters what I will not copy here because the string would be longer than my screen)

```
[a-zA-Z ,.'-]{3,30}
```

The space, and the ,.'- punctuation will do most cases, but in case anyone have suggestion what character to add please comment it.

Now my question: This regex allows having more than 1 punctuation in a row, what I would not like to allow. It is legal to have a space then one punctuation, but not legal to have two or more, Like "---"

I would also disallow starting with space ,.-, with other words I would like to enable only letters and ' as the first char. I can manage this (I hope):

```
[a-zA-Z']{1}[a-zA-Z ,.'-]{2,29}
```

...but the question how to prevent to enter a bunch of punctuation still remains

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Please surround regex parts with "`" so we can better spot them in the question.

Comment: Many flavors of regular expressions exist. What flavor do you expect in an answer? PCRE?

Comment: I am using .NET Regex (flavor)

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, you can use named Unicode classes to allow Unicode letters, and much more.

Here is a regex you can use:

```
^(?!.*\p{P}\p{P}+)[\p{L}']{1}[\p{L}\p{Zs},.'-]{2,29}$
```

`(?!.*\p{P}\p{P}+)` will disallow several punctuation symbols at a stretch.

Alternatively, you can disallow 2 or more consecutive non-letter symbols with

```
^(?!.*\P{L}\P{L}+)[\p{L}']{1}[\p{L}\p{Zs},.'-]{2,29}$
```

BUT this won't allow `comma` + `space`.

Here is a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F!.*%5Cp%7BP%7D%5Cp%7BP%7D%2B)(%3F!%5Cp%7BZs%7D)%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%27%5D%7B1%7D%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BZs%7D%2C.%27-%5D%7B2%2C29%7D%24&i=---%0D%0ADffd%2C%20ddd%2C%20%20%2C%2C%2C%0D%0A%20NameWithSpaceAtStart%0D%0ANameWithNoSpaceAtStart&o=m) (it is advisable to test each string individually on regexstorm.net, or see [alternative demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB2pL4/2)).